# What is difference between spring-jdbc.jar and org.springframework.jdbc jar? Why do we need both the jars in the project?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

In the project using both the jars spring-jdbc.jar and org.springframework.jdbc.jar. I want to remove one of the jars due to the mismatch of the version. Spring-jdbc has 4.1.4 jar version and other one is 3.2.5 which is latest for both the jar.
Due to jar version mismatch I am getting the error during runtime. Could anyone tell me the correct latest jar version for both the files.

Comment: What do you think would be the latest between 3.2.5 and 4.1.4? Do version numbers start from 100 and go back to 1? Or do they start from 0 and keep increasing?

Comment: 4.1.4 is the latest. The version is in incrementing order and generally starts from 1.x or 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Open the manifest.MF of the org.sprigframework.jdbc.jar and you will find import/export-package statements in it. 
Those jars where available on the spring ebr repository until it was closed last year. If you're not using OSGi, you can drop the old jar version, otherwise look fot apache servicemix bundles.

Comment: Thanks Martin for you reply. I will try to use only spring-jdbc as that is only latest one.